# A concave polyhedron having square and regular pentagonal faces, with two more squares than pentagons.

Tags: geometry

I need some help describing how to create a concave polyhedron that has regular square and pentagon faces, all with equal side lengths and it also must have two more square faces than pentagonal faces.

I am finding it very hard to visualise the polyhedron and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a very specific recipe. What makes you think such a polyhedron exists? Is this a textbook exercise? a contest problem? a problem you devised yourself?

Comment: It's a text book problem, the next part of the question is prove a convex polyhedron with these properties (square and Pentagon sides etc) doesn't exist

Comment: That information seems important enough to include in the question. (Comments are easily overlooked.) It would also be helpful to mention what this textbook has discussed about this topic. I would guess that [Euler's polyhedron formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Polyhedra) and other element-counting techniques come into play, but they don't necessarily distinguish "convex" and "concave". (BTW, are "self-intersecting" polyhedra allowed?) Is this a textbook on metric geometry, so that one might be expected to calculate dihedral angles and such?

Comment: What is meant by a "concave polyhedron"?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: obviously, a polyhedron that isn't convex. (And presumably non-self-intersecting $-$ if self-intersection were allowed, that should be explicitly stated.)

Comment: Can you please give a simple example of  a concave polyhedron  ?

Answer (score 4):

Start with a regular dodecahedron and stick two regular pentagonal prisms on top of two faces. You'll get a polyhedron with 12 pentagonal and 10 square faces.

Now stick a cube on top of a square face: this will add 4 more square faces, giving 12 pentagonal and 14 square faces.

[image]

Comment: Concave polyhedron?